# How to clear CMOS on a Asus TF810C tablet?

Tags: troubleshooting, tablet, cmos

I have an Asus TF810C tablet which won't boot. I thought about doing a Clear CMOS, but [the manual](http://devdb.ru/data/file/file53189bbe5b8d78.66259512.pdf) doesn't tell how to do it and doesn't even have troubleshooting section.

This is the first time I have to do this operation on a tablet.

How to do it?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to clear CMOS is simple.

Just open up the case and look for a small battery on the Motherboard.

Remove the Battery for a minute or two and then replace it.

This clears a corrupted CMOS and you will be back in business.

I have had this problem twice.

The first time a qualified engineer tried replacing the CPU to solve the problem.

I did it myself IN A MOMENT OF INSPIRATION with the BATTERY TRICK!